# Problem with running telegram bot on windows server 2012 r2

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-telegram-bot-api

I've created a telegram bot using node.js and it worked successfully on my local system... but when I tried to run it on a 2012/r2 windows server, I've constantly got the

> error: [polling_error] {"code":"ETELEGRAM","message":"ETELEGRAM: 409 Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running"}

I stopped it and once again tried it on my local machine and it worked totally fine... So what is the problem with my windows server?

P.S: I'm pretty sure the bot is run exclusively by me.

Answer (score 0):

Revoke Your Token from bot father and Start your Script Again.